# Design Principal for JPA EntityManger

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA in a web application running in Tomcat 8.  I am relatively new to JPA, and am having a hard time figuring out how to properly design my web app to use EntityManager.  I have read "Java Persistence with Hibernate" and "Pro JPA 2", as well as a few posts about Entity Managers, but I am still unclear as to how to properly design my web app.

Should I create a singleton EntityManager that is used by the web app to service all requests, such as to CRUD (create, read, update, delete) entities?

Or should I ask the EntityManagerFactory to create a new EntityManager for each user request that comes in and close the EntityManager when I'm done processing the request?

I'm currently doing development on my local machine, where I am the only user.
What are the pros/cons of each approach? 
Do both scale to hundreds of users?

I don't have the real world experience to answer these questions, so I'm looking for some answers/guidance from people who've used JPA in enterprise business apps.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-overview. *Session: A single-threaded, short-lived object conceptually modeling a "Unit of Work" PoEAA. In JPA nomenclature, the Session is represented by an EntityManager*. If you make it a singleton, it will be long-lived, and used by all the threads. What do you conclude?

Comment: Ah.  So ask the EntityManagerFactory to create a new EntityManager each time I need to perform a "unit of work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created ScopedEntityManager wrapper to ease JPA use in a servlet webapp. It creates an auto managed EM for the http request using a threadlocal variable.

It makes sure EM is rollbacked+closed after a servlet request. Same EM is  returned in a getter method for the same request thread. You just need to commit() if all is good. Throwing an exception is not a problem because the request listener take care of the rollback().

See this how to instantiate a EM wrapper and life cycle manager. 
https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager/blob/master/src/es/claro/persistence/ScopedContextListener.java

https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager

https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager/blob/master/example_webapp/webapp/jpa1.jsp

So yes create a new EntityManager for each http request.